# Java proxy server - some requests aborted, weird bug

Tags: java, http, sockets, proxy

I'm kinda new to Java language, but have a good experience in other technologies.

Right now Im working on creating a proxy server and I have come up with the code that seems to work fine for single requests, but when I'm trying to open some `html` page that loads lots of `styles`, `images` etc, part of requests just got aborted ( this is what firebug tells me )

So, will try to simplify the code and be as much specific as possible in showing up the exact problem

Here's the main class :

```
public class ProxyThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProxyThread Proxy = new ProxyThread();            
        Proxy.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(this.portNumber, 1);
        while(true) {
            Socket serverClient = server.accept();
            this._threads[threadCount] = new Thread( new RequestProcess( serverClient, threadCount++ ));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code of RequestProcess that does processing of each request

```
public class RequestProcess  implements Runnable {

    public void start()  throws InterruptedException {
        this.serverIn = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( this.serverClient.getInputStream() ) );
        this.serverOut = this.serverClient.getOutputStream()   ;

        String currentBuffer;
        String request = "";
        String host = "";
        int port = 0;

        while ((currentBuffer = this.serverIn.readLine()) != null) {
                if (currentBuffer.length() == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                request += currentBuffer + "\r\n";

                if (currentBuffer.startsWith("CONNECT ") || currentBuffer.startsWith("GET ")) {
                    host = this.parseHost( currentBuffer );
                    port = this.parsePort( currentBuffer );    
                }     
        }    
        request += "\r\n";    
        if (host.isEmpty() || request.isEmpty()) {

            throw new InterruptedException("request or host empty, so exiting ");
        }    

        clientRequestProcess clientProcess = new clientRequestProcess( host, port, request, this.threadNum );

        byte[] response = clientProcess.processRequest();

        this.serverOut.write(response);
        this.serverOut.close();    
    }
}
```

And here's the class that process request and sending it to the actual server

```
public class clientRequestProcess {    

    public byte[] processRequest()
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[256*1024];

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket( host, port );   
        clientSocket.getOutputStream().write( request.getBytes() );
        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

        int r = 1;
        while (r > 0) {
            r = is.read(buf);
            if (r > 0) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, r);      
            }
        }   
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }   
}
```

All the code is draft one and is simplified to show the big picture of how it works. All try-catch blocks, debugging info etc are missed here.

steps
 - Set up browser to use JAVA proxy
 - Open some site
 - Part of http requests are successfully processed and correct response is returned
  -**part of requests shows up as aborted in firebug. The thing is that part is absolutely random, so one time some file is loading, another it is not**

Code troubleshooting shows me that first line of request (that comes from the browser) are empty, so my condition

```
 if (currentBuffer.length() == 0) {
      break;
 }
```

breaks reading the socket and thus it ruturns nothing to the browser and connection gets aborted

I read rfc on http protocol and figured out that https requests considered to be over once \r\n meets, so that's why I'm using that condition
If I just open that file in separate tab - it loads successfully, don;t matter how many times im trying to reload it. But when a bunch of files are loaded at one time - some random of them gets aborted. So it is happening only when a lot of files loading, when one or even 3-5 - all files loads fine

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You need to enable more waiting requests in the `serverSocket` so they don't get refused.

Comment: That is a good idea, but I've already checked ServerSocket class descriptions and didn't find anything like you are suggesting
if you know exact function or parameter name that may help here - it would be very useful

Comment: Oh, I believe I found it. It  called backlog and it is setting as second parameter when creating new ServerSocket( portNumber, <Backlog_value>). Thank you for setting me to the right directon